# Which Brazilian beers are found outside Brazil?

Tags: local, distribution, brazil

In Brazil there is a very large trade in foreign beers, but in the countries I visited I never found Brazilian beers.

Can you help me with this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brahma and Bohemia are the only Brazilian beers I’ve seen in the United States but only at specialty stores. But this isn’t terribly surprising to me. The vast majority or Brazilian beer is [lager](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_in_Brazil) and in the United States, we are already flooded with a variety of cheap lager beers and plenty of local craft lager beers.

I can’t find export data for specific countries, but since the United States is one of the biggest beer markets, given the rarity here, I would expect they are increasingly rare the further you get from Brazil.